# Python - passing pointers between C and Python with ctypes

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

I'm trying to write a small, modular program in Python that will dynamically load C functions and use them to execute computationally intensive code. In this program I am creating a couple of large matrices that I will be passing back and forth between my Python code to different C functions. I would prefer to pass these matrices by reference to avoid additional computational overhead.

I've tried reading through the Python docs for ctypes, but it doesn't seem to explain how to do this. I understand, for instance, that I can use byref() or pointer() to pass a pointer from Python to a C function, but how to I pass a pointer from an external C function back to Python? Given that variables are names in Python, is this just done "automatically" (for lack of a better term) when Python receives a value from a C function?

As a concrete example, this is what I'm trying to do (in pseudo-code):

```
foo = ctypes.CDLL("pathToFoo")
bar = ctypes.CDLL("pathToBar")

# Generate a large matrix by calling a C function.
reallyBigMatrix = foo.generateReallyBigMatrix()

# Pass reallyBigMatrix to another function and perform some operation
# on it. Since the matrix is really big, I would prefer to pass a 
# reference to this matrix to my next C function rather than passing
# the matrix by value.
modifiedReallyBigMatrix = bar.modifyReallyBigMatrix(reallBigMatrix)
```

Alternatively, I'm using Python and C in conjunction as I need an easy way to dynamically load C functions in my program. I may pass paths to different C files to my Python program so that the Python program will execute the same code on different functions. As an example, I may want to run my program two different ways: keep the same "generateReallyBigMatrix" function in both runs, but used a different "modifyReallyBigMatrix" program between run 1 and run 2. If there is an easy, cross-platform way to do this in C or C++ I would be happy to implement that solution rather than using ctypes and Python. However, I haven't been able to find a simple, cross-platform solution.

Comment: What's the problem with `shared memory` ?

Comment: shared memory, as in....?

Comment: As you said, You want to pass params between C and Python, You can use `shared memory` and set variable in Python and get access to that on your C code and vice versa.

Comment: I get that you're saying to share a segment of memory between the programs, but how to I actually go about doing that?

Comment: @Ramin Shared memory is needed to pass between *processes*.  `ctypes` allows Python to call C functions in a DLL loaded in the same process, so shared memory isn't required.

Comment: Take a look at `numpy`([link](http://www.numpy.org/)).  It is a 3rd party library for Python designed to do fast matrix operations.  If it doesn't have the operations you want, you can obtain `ctypes` references and process them in C as well.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I know numpy won't have the operations I'm looking for. The matrix is actually a network representation and the operations aren't mathematical in the sense you're thinking. The second part is actually my question: how do I work with these references? Maybe I missed something in the documentation, but as I explained in my post I couldn't figure this out based on the documentation.

Comment: I just answered a similar question the other day([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43153107/235698)).  Does that help?

Comment: I'll have to take a look at it, but it looks like it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to modify the C library, or even write a wrapper for it in C yourself, or does the code to solve this problem all need to be written in Python?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Everything I am using in this, C and Python, is written from scratch. I can do anything I want with it. The real core of the problem I am trying to solve is how to pass a path to a C library to some master program, and dynamically load the functions in that library. It has to be simple, and work without a high learning curve or installing a bunch of third-party code. Python with ctypes is the best way I've found of doing that, but I can't figure out how to pass a pointer from a called C function back to the master Python program, which makes it a non-solution for me.

Comment: Cython might also be something to look at.

Answer (score 2):

You've mentioned that you are writing all the code, both Python and C, from yourself.  I suggest not using `ctypes` for this, as `ctypes` is best suited for using C libraries that cannot be modified.

Instead, write a module in C using the [Python C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html).  It will expose a single function to start with, like this:

```
PyObject* generateReallyBigMatrix(void);
```

Now, instead of trying to return a raw C pointer, you can return any Python object that you like.  Good choices here would be to return a NumPy array (using the [NumPy C API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html)), or to return a [Python "buffer"](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) (from which a NumPy array can be constructed in Python if desired).

Either way, once this function is written in C using the appropriate APIs, your Python code will be simple:

```
import foo
reallyBigMatrix = foo.generateReallyBigMatrix()
```

To do it using the NumPy C API, your C code will look like this:

```
PyObject* generateReallyBigMatrix(void)
{
    npy_intp dimension = 100;
    PyArray_Descr* descr;
    PyArray_DescrAlignConverter2("float64", &descr); // use any dtype

    PyObject* array = PyArray_Empty(1, &dimension, descr, 0/*fortran*/);
    Py_DECREF(descr);

    void* data = PyArray_DATA(array);
    // TODO: populate data

    return array;
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"generateReallyBigMatrix", generateReallyBigMatrix, METH_VARARGS, "doc"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initfoo(void)
{
    import_array(); // enable NumPy C API
    Py_InitModule("foo", methods);
}
```

Note that the NumPy C API requires a slightly strange [initialization ritual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#importing-the-api).  See also [Numpy C API: Link several object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253389/numpy-c-api-link-several-object-files)

You then compile the code as a shared library called `foo.so` (no `lib` prefix).